# Excel XML attribute to not show grid lines

Tags: excel, xml

I have an xml file that I open with Excel which is generated by a very simple script that just output the required XML to a file. I would like that the grid-lines do not appear in the first worksheet. Does any one know what XML attributes/section must be add to the XML file so that the gridLines do not appear?

The below is just a simple small sample of the xml file. I would like the grid lines not to appear in the first tab. The second tab should have grid lines. I'm trying to figure out what to put in the worksheet (in the XML) to achieve this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<Worksheet ss:Name="FIRST WITH NO GRID">
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="65100" x:FullColumns="1"
 x:FullRows="1">
<Column ss:Width="100"/>
<Column ss:Width="100"/>
<Column ss:Width="100"/>
<Row>
<Cell ss:Index="1" ><Data ss:Type="String">FIRST</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="2" ><Data ss:Type="String">SECOND</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="3" ><Data ss:Type="String">THIRD</Data></Cell>
</Row>
</Table>
</Worksheet>
<Worksheet ss:Name="SECOND WITH GRID">
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="65100" x:FullColumns="1"
 x:FullRows="1">
<Column ss:Width="100"/>
<Column ss:Width="100"/>
<Column ss:Width="100"/>
<Row>
<Cell ss:Index="1" ><Data ss:Type="String">FIRST</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="2" ><Data ss:Type="String">SECOND</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="3" ><Data ss:Type="String">THIRD</Data></Cell>
</Row>
</Table>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Any input would help. I trying to find documentation on what XML tags and attributes are recognized by Excel. If anyone can share a link to this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try saving a workbook to that format after turning off the gridline display? 
 I see `<DoNotDisplayGridlines/>` which seemsl ike a good candidate for what you want...

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. It is exactly what was required. I added the following to the first worksheet and it worked perfectly: <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <DoNotDisplayGridlines/>
</WorksheetOptions>

Answer (score 0):

The XML needs to include styles, which can then be applied to cells.

```
  opening XML tag    
  <Workbook ....>
   <Styles>
     <Style ss:ID="myStyle">
       <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
       <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
       </Borders>
       <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="28" ss:Color="#000000"/>
       <Interior ss:Color="#808080" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
      </Style>
    </Styles>

[...snip...]  
  <Worksheet ...>
   <Table ...>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="27">
    <Cell ss:MergeAcross="2" ss:StyleID="myStyle"><Data ss:Type="String">Heading</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

**edit after comments:**
The worksheet grid can be turned off with the `showGridLines` property in the `sheetView` node

```
<sheetViews>
    <sheetView showGridLines="0" workbookViewId="0">
        <selection activeCell="B5" sqref="B5"/>
    </sheetView>
</sheetViews>
```

You can easily discover settings like these by creating an Excel file, rename it with a .zip ending and look at the xml in the worksheets folder of the zip file.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn. This will add solid lines to the cells that need a borders (which is one of the things that I need to do). However, what I was hoping is a way to get rid of the global grid that you can get rid of when you uncheck the "View" checkbox in "Gridlines" of the "Sheet Options" of the "Page Layout". I was hoping to find a option to do this globally in XML for the whole sheet and not cell by cell (as it is possible to do it in excel itself)

Answer (score 0):

Tim provided the answer for this. Added this to the first worksheet did the trick:

```
<WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <DoNotDisplayGridlines/>
</WorksheetOptions>
```